# Java: Cannot find variable after it has been defined

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap, hashtable

I am trying to create a dummy `Node` that allows me to traverse a `LinkedList` object that I have created, beginning at that LinkedList's `.first` `Node` and continuing until it has no more values. The problem that I am having, specifically, is that when I create a dummy `Node`, Java doesn't recognize the variable which I have just used to define my dummy `Node`. Observe in the following code:

```
private MyLinkedList extract(int x){
MyLinkedList values = new MyLinkedList();
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
  Node p = table[i].first;
  while(table[i].p != null){
    values.add(p.value);
    p = p.next;
  }
}
return values;
}
```

The error arises in the `while` loop booelan statement and I am told that Java "cannot find symbol  :  variable p"

Any idea why? Thanks!

Some variable definitions for your convenience:

table = hashtable of MyLinkedLists;

x = size of hashtable;

Comment: What you think `table[i].p` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Node p = table[i].first;
  while(table[i].p != null){
    values.add(p.value);
    p = p.next;
  }
```

unless the return value of `table[i]` contains a variable p , you can't use it

Answer (score 1):

`p` is a local variable, it's not a member of the instance referred by the `table[i]` reference.

Try :

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
  Node p = table[i].first;
  while(p != null){
    values.add(p.value);
    p = p.next;
  }
}
```